# How to iterate with some "memory" mechanism?

Tags: python, recursion, memory, queue

Given a function `f(x)`, the goal is recursively call `f(x)` but with memory of the output 2 steps before. I.e.:

```
>>> def f(x): return x**2
... 
>>> memory = original = 3
>>> x0 = f(original)
>>> x1 = f(x0+memory)
>>> memory = x0
>>> x2 = f(x1+memory)
>>> memory = x1
>>> x3 = f(x2+memory)
>>> memory = x2
>>> x4 = f(x3+memory)
>>> x4
307766666167459524
```

I could save a list and then store all the outputs of each iteration in the recursion:

```
>>> original = 3
>>> memory = []
>>> memory.append(original)
>>> memory.append(f(original))
>>> for i in range(4):
...     memory.append(f(memory[-1]+memory[-2]))
... 
>>> memory[-1]
307766666167459524
```

But imagine that saving these output is an expensive task, given that the actual `f(x)` I'm using stores some gianormous number of floating points and it's not simply doing a square.

I could also just store the last 2 memory slots with fancy `deque`:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> original = 3
>>> q = deque([original, f(original)])
>>> for i in range(4):
...     q.append(f(q[-1]+q.popleft()))
... 
>>> q[-1]
307766666167459524
```

**How else can I perform such recursion function with some form of memory mechanism?**

Imagine if the memory is more complicated and I need to store not just -2 but -n and I have to access [-n:-1] elements? Would your solution accommodate that?

Answer (score 1):

Python generators are a good solution when you have to deal with infinite sequence.

In your example, if you need to access only the two last elements, you can use the below generator function:

```
def f_generator(x):
    l = [x, f(x)]
    while True:
        res = f(l[0]+l[1])
        l.pop(0)
        l.append(res)
        yield res

outputs = f_generator(3)
for i in range(4):
    print(outputs.next())
```

If you need to access more than two elements in your generator function, you will need to make it more generic by passing as argument the number of elements to access, and modifying the list initialization (`l = [x, f(x)]`) and the computation of the next element (`res = f(l[0]+l[1])`).

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your problem:

mem = [3, 9]

for i in range(2, x):

```
mem.append(f(mem[-1] + mem[-2]))
# if mem have more than n elements, pop the first one
if len(mem) > n:
    mem.pop(0)
```

## now if x is big enough mem will store n values and f(x-i) = mem[-i]

Answer (score 0):

A generator sounds like what you're after as it will lazily generate the next element in your sequence. If you make it generic enough you can reuse it later with:

- different functions
- different seeds, and
- different memory lengths

For example:

```
def do_on_last_n_generator(f, n, seed):
internal_list = [seed]
while True:
    internal_list.append(f(internal_list, n))
    if len(internal_list)>n:
        internal_list.pop(0)
    yield internal_list[-1]
```

Then you can supply a function, e.g.

```
def my_sum_func(a_list, n): # sum the last n elements
    return sum(a_list[-n:])
```

Then make yourself a generator. Here you can decide the seed number (I'm using 1) and the memory elements (here I'll use 4):

```
sum_last_four = do_on_last_n_generator(my_sum_func, 4, 1)
```

Then each time you want to get the next element:

```
next_number = next(sum_last_four)
```

or you can get them in a loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(next(sum_last_four)
```

If later on you decide you actually want to sum the last ten elements, just make a new generator:

```
sum_last_ten = do_on_last_n_generator(my_sum_func, 10, 1)
```

You can similarly change the function and seed.